# Can I include a Metamorphosis Machine in my HQ/Installation to get a supply of superpowered minions?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e

In the Powers chapter of the sourcebook Gadget Guide, it lists the Metamorphosis Machine as a device that can empower people to superhuman states, using the following power:

> Metamorphosis Machine: Summon Empowered Version, General Type, Limited to Available Subjects • 2 points per rank

If I use the Effect option for my Headquarters/Installation, I get to spend up to 20 power points (in a PL 10 campaign) to design a power that can be used inside my base. If I select the Metamorphosis Machine as such an Effect, would I be able to get an arbitrary number of previously-transformed minions for the cost of a single Equipment Point? Would I need to take a different feature to get untransformed minions first, and if I do, would the transformed minions be restricted the same way the original minions were (e.g. if they were originally my Headquarters' Personnel, would they still be restricted to only being able to act inside the base), or would they be considered a completely unrelated entity within the rules of the game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### As Written? No.

You get one super powered minion, and can replace that one with a different super powered minion. But you can only have one, not an arbitrary horde.

[Summon](https://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/effects/effect-descriptions/summon-control/) is a specific power, with specific mechanics. It provides one Dazed Minion, with a friendly attitude, the same minion every time, and the minion must recover fully before it can be summoned again.

The **Metamorphosis Machine** alters summon by adding the Variable (General Type) modifier, allowing a different Minion to be summoned each time, and a Limitation of available subjects. When you install the machine, you define the general type - dogs, cats, humans, fish, etc.

The Minion is still Dazed (no Active or Heroic modifiers), you can only transform one at a time (no Horde modifier), and you can only have one minion active at a time (no Multiple Minions modifiers).

Because the Machine uses the Summon power, it has to follow all the rules of the Summon power.